# Deducing local bound from global bound for zeros of Riemann $\zeta(s)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am considering a function related to the Riemann zeta function, and I have a asymptotic for the cardinality of the zeros less than $T$, of the form
$$N(T) = cT^2 + O(T)$$
when $T$ is large. Apparently it is possible from this "global" information the "local" fact that there are few zeros in small balls, precisely that the number of zeros $\rho$ such that $|s - \rho| < 2$ is $O(Im(|s|))$.

I do not see any reason for this to be true (at least for a general function, zeros can be globally few while concentrating in specific small balls). Where the specific structure of the Riemann zeta function comes into play? Are there precise references for it?

Comment: For $\zeta$ since the trivial zeroes are on the real axis, we can focus on the zeroes in the critical strip and for those, the only important facts are the polynomial bounds for $\zeta$ on vertical lines, namely $|\zeta(\sigma+it)| \le t^A, -1 \le \sigma \le 5$ since then Jensen theorem immediately implies that $N(T+1)-N(T)=O(\log T)$ - see Titchmarsh RZ book page 211; so if you have the same stuff (zeroes in a finite strip, polynomial bounds on vertical lines uniform in strips), same proof applies - note though that your asymptotic gives $N(T+1)=cT^2+2cT+1+O(T)$ so $N(T+1)-N(T)=O(T)$ directly

Comment: More generally (uniform) bounds on vertical lines and zeroes in strips give estimates for $N(T+1)-N(T)$ even if those bounds are not polynomial but exponential as polynomial bounds on strips imply that $N(T)=O(T\log T)$ so do not really apply in your case

Comment: It follows from the fact that for all real $\sigma$ there exists a constant $A(\sigma)>0$ such that $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|<|t|^{A(\sigma)}$ for large $|t|$, which gives an $O(\log T)$ bound for the number of zeros in the strip $T<t\le T+1$ via Jensen's theorem.

Comment: Doesn't what you want follow from the fact that $N(T+1)-N(T) = O(T)$?

Comment: @DavidFarmer I would exactly understand that point, I do not see how to "localize" the size of the cardinality $N(T)$ to a small ball around a certain point (I interpret it this way)

Comment: That was @Conrad's point: do you know that the zeros lie in a strip?  That is, do you have a bound on the real parts of the zeros?

Comment: @DavidFarmer Yes, so I need to use Titschmarch-like arguments (based on Jensen theorem) to deduce it, right?

Comment: The ball you care about lies in a strip of *fixed constant* width $A$.  You know $N(T+2A)-N(T)=O(T)$, as in @Conrad first comment.  Choose $T$ to be the height of the center of the ball.  So there are $O(T)$ zeros inside a part of the strip containing the ball you care about.  Therefore $O(T)$ inside the ball inside that part of the strip.

The implied constant in $O(T)$ depends on $A$, but you said that is a fixed constant not depending on $T$.